# Unable to Run Build Task (Ctrl Shift B) in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, I have the following build task (tasks.json) set up and it was working until today.

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "0.1.0",
"command": "tsc",
"isShellCommand": true,
"args": ["-p", "."],
"showOutput": "always",
"problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

I did upgrade VSCode to 1.12.1 so I'm wondering if that upgrade is why this is no longer working.  Basically now when I hit Ctrl Shift B, nothing happens.  Usually a spinning icon displays at the bottom and then errors display in the task output. Now nothing occurs.  I can still build on the command successfully (tsc -p .)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I configured my VS Code:

#### tasks.json

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "python",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "args": [
                "setup.py",
                "install"
            ],
            "presentation": {
                "echo": true,
                "panel": "shared",
                "focus": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue went away after I upgraded my Visual Studio Team Services extension.